# VBA "restore to calculated column formula"

Tags: vba, excel

I have a program that I am almost finished with that sorts an excel sheet by Number, ID, and Date (new-old), then removes rows that don't have any of the specific numbers I want in the Number column, then puts a formula in a new column to find the first occurrence of every new ID. When I run it, the entire last column says "1" and it has a green triangle in the top left which if I click it gives me the option to "restore to calculated column formula". When I click that it numbers it how I want it to, except it starts at the 3rd row which messes up all the numbers. I think the problem has something to do with removing rows. How can I fix this using VBA(has to be automated)?
My code:

```
'sorting
Dim tName As String
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Sort
    tName = .Parent.Name 'list name

    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range(tName & "[Number]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
        Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range(tName & "[ID]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
        Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range(tName & "[Date]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
        Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

'deletes all rows that arent the right #
Dim firstrow As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
With Sheets(1)
    firstrow = 2
    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    For Lrow = lastrow To firstrow Step -1
        With .Cells(Lrow, "A")
            If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If .Value <> "407" And .Value <> "412" And .Value <> "416" And .Value <> "419" And .Value <> "445" And .Value <> "434" And .Value <> "441" And .Value <> "4100" And .Value <> "440" And .Value <> "486" And .Value <> "428" And .Value <> "417" Then
                    .EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next Lrow
End With

'restore to calculated column formula?
'puts formula in last column to find newest
Dim targetRow As Long
With ActiveSheet
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'new lastrow bc deleted
End With
Dim cell As Range
targetRow = 2
Sheets(1).Range("AJ" & 1).Value = "Selection"
Columns("AJ:AJ").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "General" 'formatting bc previous column is text

For Each cell In Sheets(1).Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
    Sheets(1).Range("AJ" & targetRow).Value = "=COUNTIF($D$2:D2,D2)"
    targetRow = targetRow + 1
Next cell
```